# Reactjs slick slide

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

I am making a very simple slider in reactjs using `reactstrap`(bootstrap)..

Working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-brook-fz5mm

```
    <CarouselItem
      onExiting={this.onExiting}
      onExited={this.onExited}
      key={item.src}
    >
      <img width="100%" src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
      <CarouselCaption
        captionText={item.caption}
        captionHeader={item.caption}
      />
    </CarouselItem>
```

Here each image gets slide when we click on the `indicator` or else the `control` but I don't want this behaviour.

I would like do have exactly like in the link https://react-multi-carousel.now.sh/

Here in this link we can move the slide using mouse sliding left and right..

So I would like to achieve the same using reactstrap in reactjs..

Any modifications to the existing implementation would also welcome (strictly no jquery) but I need to achieve the slick like behaviour with this reactstrap carousel implementation.

I have implemented the above sample from official `reactstrap` : https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/ , So the properties mentioned by them have been used in my example as well..

As I am new in reactjs and reactstrap please consider this question and help me to achieve this behaviour..

Comment: Okay, Is it the complete code? what's the body of `onExiting, onExited` because that's what makes the difference.

Comment: @its4zahoor, Yes this is my complete code and as I said I am using reactstrap, the properties ```onExiting``` and ```onExited``` comes along with it.. Ref: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use react-slick to achieve similar behavior.
You can add properties in settings object to show number of elements on each slide.
https://react-slick.neostack.com/

```
import Slider from 'react-slick';

export default function Slide() {
  const settings = {
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };

  return (
    <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      );
    }
```

Comment: I need to achieve this only using reactstrap and no more other libraries..